# Get git difftool to send its own diff to viewer

Tags: git, configuration, diff

`git difftool --dir-diff/-d` apparently copies/links everything to a tmpdir and makes the external tool do the diff on those directories.

This doesn’t play well with the `--find-renames/-M` option, which makes git find paths of moved files and sends all found path pairs to the diff tool.

i basically want git to just pipe its own diff into `kompare -o -`. Is it possible to configure `git difftool` to do that